# Sample use the broswerTarget option of ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to automatically open Chrome when building my Angular apps. However, I can't use -o because my default browser is Safari (I don't wish to change the default browser).

It seems that --browserTarget is all that I need, but when I run something like:

```
ng serve --browserTarget=Chrome
```

The CLI throws an error:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
    Data path ".browserTarget" should match patter ".+:.+(:.+)?"
```

I can't seem to find any documentation or samples on how to use this option to rectify that issue.

Thanks in advance,
Wayne

Comment: I am also looking for this configuration but it appears that browserTarget is to generate the build for specific browser. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L521-L906

Comment: Just for reference: https://angular.io/cli/serve

Answer (score 2):

Found some information on this from [an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16572) on the repo for angular-cli. It is used to specify which build configuration to use while serving.

[From this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16572#issuecomment-574130614)

> The serve command doesn't completely know how to build it, it just knows how to serve it.

> Usually there's only one build, but since a target can have multiple configurations, you can specify that you want to serve that particular configuration of the build.

> Where "browserTarget": "next-app:build" means "I want to serve projects->next-app with the default options" and "browserTarget": "next-app:build:production" means "I want to serve projects->next-app with the default options merged with the production config".

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours for the answer to this question and didn't find much, aside from your question.  I'm an Angular noob, and not qualified to answer, but this question has been viewed 650 times so far, and nobody else has provided an answer yet.  So, at least when I forget it and come back searching for a solution again in a year, I'll find the following better-than-nothing answer.

It seems that the --browserTarget flag is a red herring.  The solution I implemented is to use the open-cli package from here:  [open-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open-cli) --
Installed as follows:

```
> npm install --global open-cli
```

And then, in the "scripts": {...} section of the package.json file (in the root folder of my Angular project), I replaced this line:

```
"start": "ng serve",
```

with this line:

```
"start": "open-cli http://localhost:4200 -- 'chrome' && ng serve",
```

Note the above is for use on a Windows machine.  The use of 'chrome' here is platform-dependent.  Use 'google-chrome' on Linux, 'google chrome' on a Mac, and 'chrome' on Windows.

Then from the command line, I issue the following command to start the server & open my (non-default) Chrome browser:

```
> npm start
```

There are a couple of drawbacks with this approach for which I hope people will gently point out and suggest improvements in the comments (or in another answer):

1. I've hard-coded the port, which could/should surely be pulled from elsewhere dynamically.
2. The browser opens before the page is done compiling, and thus starts with a "Connection Refused Error", which could cause confusion.  With patience, the browser automatically refreshes once the build is complete and the Angular server starts, but it takes several seconds.

Comment: This would actually work w/out the 2nd issue if you just put `ng serve && ` before the open-cli command. I bet the port could be a variable somehow as well. But that's not too bad of an idea.